# Swagger 2.0 (Open Api 3.0) with Play Framework 2.6 (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, swagger, openapi

There is [swagger-play](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play) plugin, that says to support Swagger 2.0, however actually it uses [swagger annotations 1.5.x](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X), not 2.0, thus, not supporting Open Api 3.0.

Has anyone managed to wire Open Api 3 with Play Framework using code-first interface declaration?

I tried to declare explicit swagger-core dependency as

```
"io.swagger.core.v3" % "swagger-core" % "2.0.5"
```

but with no success, i.e. I get errors at initializing plugin:

```
[error] 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters
[error]   at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl.<init>(SwaggerPlugin.scala:35)
[error]   while locating play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl
[error]   at play.modules.swagger.SwaggerModule.bindings(SwaggerModule.scala:11):
[error] Binding(interface play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPlugin to ConstructionTarget(class play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPluginImpl) eagerly) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
[error]   while locating play.modules.swagger.SwaggerPlugin
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems the Open API 3.0 support in swagger-play is not planned in immediate future as per this - [Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0 support?](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play/issues/159).

An alternate solution for this can be [iheartradio/play-swagger](https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger). Reference to this alternative is also mentioned in the  [swagger-play](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play) But with this alternate api you can specify the Open API 3.0 Specs as **comments** in the form of JSON or YAML inside your play **Route** file and not as an annotation in controller.

Alternatively the specs can be maintained (using [swagger-editor](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-editor/))  in a separate JSON / YAML file and can be viewed/exposed via [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) or other Open API spec supporting viewer like [OpenAPI-GUI](https://mermade.github.io/openapi-gui/).